# Actions on google - smart home - REQUEST_SYNC

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

We have an smart home app with actions on google and already implemented the SYNC, QUERY and EXECUTE intents.

Now, we would like to implement the REQUEST_SYNC intent (mentionned in the fig. 2 [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/). However, we cannot find any documentation about it's implementation. Did anyone already implemented it?

Comment: Any chance you found an answer and just haven't supplied it back here yet?

Comment: Hi Michael, unfortunatly I did notn't find the answer. If a google engineer comes by here ;).

Comment: For further reference, google updated the documentation: https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app#request-sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google updated their example Node.js code with request sync functionality:
https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs

Refer to the last commit.
Maybe you can start here.

Comment: Yeah I saw it. Unfortunately, it uses an API that doesn't seem to be public or published yet: homegraph.googleapis.com. I have an open issue on that repo: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs/issues/18

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be available now.
I use
`https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:requestSync?key= &lt; KEY &gt;` with a json body content of `agent_user_id: &lt; agent userid &gt;`

search for "request sync" on page: https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app